# Get List of Elements in Page as Objects - returns always attributes of the first object

Tags: java, selenium, pageobjects

EDITED:
I need is to get list of 3 objects on a page and make actions on them.
E.g. I have a Shop and some 3 items added to cart (Apple, Pear, Cucumber). I want to traverse through each item BUT also to click on some button on item[i]

I got very confused and don't know why it returns a list of 3 elements, but when I `getListOfProducts().get(1).getName` or `(2)` it will always return attributes for the first one (Apple).

```
My Cart page:

    public class CartPage extends BasePage {
    
    public static Product productInCart;

    @FindBy(css = "div[class*='locatorName']") //same for 3 tiles
    public List<WebElement> productList;

    public List<WebElement> getProductList() {
        return productList;
    }
    
        public CartPage(){
            PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
        }
    
    public List<Product> getListOfProducts() {
            List<Product> productList = new ArrayList<>();
            List<WebElement> list1 = getProductList();
            for (WebElement elem : list1) {
                productInCart = new Product(elem);
                productList.add(productInCart);
            }
            return productList;
        }
    }
```

//it returns 3 elements, but all with attributes of the first element

```
public class Product extends BasePage {
    private WebElement elem;

public Product(WebElement product) {
        this.elem = product;
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
    }

//some Webelements etc
}



public class BasePage {
    public WebDriver driver;
    public Wait wait;

    public BasePage(){
        this.driver = Config.driver; //normal FF driver
        this.wait = new Wait(this.driver);
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
    }
```

Comment: Can you add the implementation of the `PageFactory.initElements()` and the `getProductList()` method? The answer might be hidden there. It may be initialization issue.

Comment: I edited main post

Comment: @Aethernite let me add that getProductList(); and Webelements elems are 3 different items (correct), but when they are added to productInCart = new Product(elem);         productList.add(productInCart); <- then it refers to the first one :(